# Parsing continuous bit stream in python using Construct module

Tags: python, binary, construct

I'm trying to parse a binary data packet in python with Construct module and have successfully parsed the header part (like data length) but according to packet spec part of the data inside the packet is encoded using continuous bit stream and last byte padded to align to byte boundary.
How should I describe it in Struct constructor? I tried Field and Bytes but no success.

Comment: Did you check [Tutorial #2](http://construct.wikispaces.com/tut-bitwise)?

Comment: [Tutorial #2](http://construct.wikispaces.com/tut-bitwise) helped and seems like BitStruct is the way to go. Thank you @JanneKarila